# Java do-while loop doesn't see closing statement

Tags: java, syntax-error

I am putting all my code into a **do-while** statement so it keeps looping until the user enters 3 to quit.  For some reason when I close the do statement it doesn't see the variable `userInput`.  I've tried changing so many things around and none of it works.  So the issue is at `while (userInput !=3);` it throws `userInput cannot be resolved to a variable`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    

do {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Please choose your choice from the following menu");
        
        System.out.print("\n1) Print through all integer numbers between two given integers");
        System.out.print("\n2) Display a right triangular pattern of stars");
        System.out.println("\n3) Quit");

        int userInput = in.nextInt();
     
        if (userInput == 1) {
                System.out.print("Enter the start number: ");
                int firstInteger = in.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
                int secondInteger = in.nextInt();
            
        while (firstInteger <= secondInteger) {
                System.out.print(firstInteger + " ");
                firstInteger++;
                
                
            }
                    
        }else if (userInput == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter the height: ");
                int triangleHeight = in.nextInt();
                
            }
            
          }  while (userInput != 3); 
            
        }
     
      }
```

Comment: The SCOPE of `userInput` needs to be outside the {curly braces} if you want that final statement to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userInput` must be declared outside the loop for the `while` condition to see it.

Try this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int userInput;

        do {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Please choose your choice from the following menu");

            System.out.print("\n1) Print through all integer numbers between two given integers");
            System.out.print("\n2) Display a right triangular pattern of stars");
            System.out.println("\n3) Quit");

            userInput = in.nextInt();

            if (userInput == 1) {
                System.out.print("Enter the start number: ");
                int firstInteger = in.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
                int secondInteger = in.nextInt();

                while (firstInteger <= secondInteger) {
                    System.out.print(firstInteger + " ");
                    firstInteger++;

                }

            } else if (userInput == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter the height: ");
                int triangleHeight = in.nextInt();

            }

        } while (userInput != 3);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`userInput` is defined inside the loop's block, so it's not accessible from outside it, including the loop's condition. One solution is to move the declaration out of it:

```java
int userInput = -1;
do {
    // code...
    userInput = in.nextInt();
    // more code...
} while (userInput != 3);
```

Comment: I see.  I need it inside the do loop though.  Every time they go through an option I need it to loop back to it asking them to choose one off the following menu,

Comment: @PythonC You need to **access** it inside the loop. The doesn't mean you need to **declare** it inside the loop. See my answer - the variable is **declared** outside the loop, but **used** inside it.